# How can i concat the values in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Please find the below code, The below code is sql server code[Stored Procedure] i am converting sql to mysql in this link [mysql](http://www.sqlines.com/online)   and below is the sql SP

```
USE databasename
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE GetSbsberIDbyDept
    @P_DepartmentIds varchar(max),
    @OP_ID varchar(max) output
AS
BEGIN
     Declare @Position int
     Declare @length int
     Declare @value varchar(8000)
     Declare @SubscribrIDs varchar(max)
     Declare @FinalSubscriberids varchar(max) = ''
     SET @Position = 0
     SET @length = 0
     select @P_DepartmentIds
         WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @P_DepartmentIds, @Position+1)>0
           BEGIN
             set @Length = CHARINDEX(',', @P_DepartmentIds, @Position+1) - @Position
             set @value = SUBSTRING(@P_DepartmentIds, @Position, @length)
             select @SubscribrIDs = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cast(SubscriberId as varchar(max)) from SbsberDetails  
             where Deptid =  @value and ParentId is null order by SubscriberId asc FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,2,'')
             if(@SubscribrIDs is not null)
              begin
                set @FinalSubscriberids += cast(@SubscribrIDs as varchar(max)) + ',';
              end
              set @Position = CHARINDEX(',', @P_DepartmentIds, @Position + @length) +1
           END
           SET @OP_ID =  @FinalSubscriberids
END
```

And i converted to MySql but i am getting the error in STUFF statement like **STUFF is not valid input at this position**, below is the Mysql code

```
    USE databasename     
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetSbsberIDbyDept(
    p_P_DepartmentIds longtext,
    p_OP_ID out longtext )
BEGIN
     Declare v_Position int;
     Declare v_length int;
     Declare v_value varchar(8000);
     Declare v_SubscribrIDs longtext;
     Declare v_FinalSubscriberids longtext Default '';
     SET v_Position = 0;
     SET v_length = 0;
     select p_P_DepartmentIds
         WHILE; CHARINDEX(',', p_P_DepartmentIds, v_Position+1)>0
           BEGIN
             set v_length = CHARINDEX(',', p_P_DepartmentIds, v_Position+1) - v_Position;
             set v_value = SUBSTRING(p_P_DepartmentIds, v_Position, v_length);
             set v_SubscribrIDs = STUFF((SELECT Concat(', ' , cast(SubscriberId as longtext)) from SbsberDetails  
             where Deptid =  v_value and ParentId is null order by SubscriberId asc FOR XML; PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,2,'')
             if(v_SubscribrIDs is not null)
              then
                set v_FinalSubscriberids += concat(cast(v_SubscribrIDs as longtext) , ',');
              end if;
              set v_Position = CHARINDEX(',', p_P_DepartmentIds, v_Position + v_length) +1;
           END;
           SET p_OP_ID =  v_FinalSubscriberids;            
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

How do i convert the above sql code to MySql?

Comment: share your sample data and expected output that would be helpful to help you

Comment: Hi @ZaynulAbadinTuhin, I edited the code, and i am using workbench

Comment: If you are working with workbench it should give you a clear error.

Comment: Yes, the error is: "STUFF" is no valid input at this position.   In MySql STUFF is not allowed right? How to write the correct syntax instead of stuff

Comment: The first error I get is in line 6: `unexpected 'out' (out)`. Solve that first.

Comment: @Chandu you shared your code only but please share sample data and your expected sample output

Comment: ` out p_OP_ID longtext` this should be correct
and im not getting any output till now, and we need to pass the parameter of GetSbsberIDbyDept proc

Comment: You should explain what the code is supposed to be doing and provide sample data and desired results.  If you are going to translate code, you need to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

STUFF is SQL server function so it's thrown error in mysql, The thing that i got  your are trying to row concat but in mysql there is funtion name [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for group cancating ,so you can use it instead of stuff

Comment: I used Group_concat, but same error  `select group_concat(SubscriberId) from  ( select Concat(', ',cast(SubscriberId as longtext)) from SubscriberDetails  where Deptid =  v_value and ParentId is null order by SubscriberId asc)'

Comment: `set v_SubscribrIDs = SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SubscriberId as longtext from SubscriberDetails where Deptid =  v_value and ParentId is null order by SubscriberId asc)'

Comment: I have not found group by clause in your sql statement sample query  SELECT student_name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score
                      ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
       FROM student
       GROUP BY student_name;